# Does this hard disk match with the HP ProLiant ML350 G5?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, hp, hp-proliant

I've got an offering for the 300 GB SAS 10K 2,5" hard disk. Will this fit in my HP ProLiant ML350 G5 server.

The description in the manual isn't that clear. I'm just don't want to buy something that doesn't fit.

Thanks in advance!

---

I didn't have much information at the asking of the question. I thought maybe some of you have more knowledge about server disks than I do and were able to give me the information i needed.

However, after requisting the P/N with the seller, I found that this was almost identical to the disks I use now and that the P/N was mentioned in my server's manual.

For people who are interested, the P/N i got was 492620-B21. The disks I own now, have the P/N 459512-001.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The vast majority of 2.5" drives you'll see for ProLiants will fit in systems from G5-G7.

However, Gen8 and newer HP servers use a different disk form-factor. The OP should post a photo or part or part number of the drive in question.

*G5 disk on left. Gen8 disk on right.*
[image]

Answer (score -1):

according to the [quick specs](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/getDocument.aspx?docname=c04284193)

> Up to eight SFF (2.5") or six LFF (3.5") Hot Plug Serial Attached SCSI
>   (SAS) or Serial-ATA (SATA) hard drives Maximum of 6TB of internal
>   storage capacity (using Hot-Plug SATA drives)

and to your description, looks like they fit.

Comment: You don't know that. HP drives have two different form-factors, and there isn't clear information about what the OP plans to buy (e.g. no part number, full description or photo).

Comment: @ewwhite - related to "HP drives have two different form-factors" - you refer to the drive cage ? +1 for the part number , I thought about that but forgot to add it in.